# The effect of random projections on matrices

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, sp.spectral-theory, random-matrices

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a given normal matrix, i.e. $A^TA=AA^T$. Let $P_s\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a random projection matrix to an $s$-dimensional subspace in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Suppose $\frac{A+A^T} {2}$ is positive semidefinite with rank $l$. Then can we say anything about the distribution of the eigenvalues of the following random matrix?
$$\frac{PA+A^TP}{2}$$
Is it still positive semidefinite? Let $\mu_1,...,\mu_k$ be the non-zero eigenvalues of it where $k\leq s\wedge l$. What is the expectation of $\prod_{i=1}^k\mu_i$?

Answer (score 1):

If $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix},P=\begin{pmatrix}1/4&\sqrt{3}/4\\\sqrt{3}/4&3/4\end{pmatrix}$, then $PA+A^TP$ is not $\geq 0$.

However, we can show that $tr(PA+A^TP)\geq 0$ (under the condition that $P$ is an orthogonal projection).